# Is it sound to calculate a stock's Adjusted High/Low value?

Tags: stock-analysis

I'm trying to get a method to get the high and low values of stocks after taking into account factors such as dividends, stock splits and new stock offerings to determine its value.

I see "Adjusted Closing" values displayed on various sites, but no "Adjusted High" or "Adjusted Low" values. Is there a reason for this?

Is it sound to calculate the Adjusted High by doing a simple (Adjusted Close/Close) * High?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there are alternative methods of adjusting the high and the low but from what I have seen, your formula is correct:

> Is it sound to calculate the Adjusted High by doing a simple (Adjusted Close/Close) * High?

For example, here's an explanation of how [Stockcharts](https://support.stockcharts.com/doku.php?id=policies:adjusted_data) does it. See the section titled: **Dividend Adjustment Calculation Details**.